# What is the term to describe the complement of a support set?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

> In mathematics, the **support** of a real-valued function $f$ is the subset
>   of the domain containing those elements which are not mapped to zero.

So, what is the term to describe **the complement of the support**, i.e., the subset of the domain containing those elements which are mapped to zero?
Is it non-support set?

Answer (score 1):

If the support is $\{ x \mid f(x)\ne 0 \}$ then its complement $\{x \mid f(x)=0 \}$ is the [fiber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_%28mathematics%29) of $0$.

Note, though, the next sentence in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)) you quote (without attribution):

> If the domain of $f$ is a topological space, the support of $f$ is instead defined as the smallest *closed* set containing all points not mapped to zero.

In that case the complement of the support would be the *interior* of the fiber of zero.